# Rails Rspec - undefined method `session'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rspec

Im testing my Session Controller but Im getting this error, the log in feature works, I tested it on the browser but Im new to testing on Rspec and can't get this to work

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response.session[:user_id]).to eq(@user_attr.id)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `session' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0xd30df10>
 # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the code of my controller:

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:user][:username])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

Rspec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionsController, type: :controller do
describe "get Login page" do
    it "returns http status" do
        get :new
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
end

describe "session" do
    before(:each) do
        @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        @user_attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user) 
    end

    it "gives session" do
        request.session[:user_id] = nil
        post :create, user: @user_attr
        expect(response.session[:user_id]).to eq(@user_attr.id)
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`session` is a variable that is available without the request/response context as shown in your example.  If you want to manipulate it or check the values it contains, you can simply do something like this:

```
it "gives session" do
    session[:user_id] = nil
    post :create, user: @user_attr
    expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(@user_attr.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much; it took a long time to find this advice.  However, it works for controller specs and I have a request spec which is redirecting to log in, and I cannot set the session to indicate that a user is logged in when making the request.